# Android SQLite reading

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to only read data from the SQLite database. When I am creating database and reading it it is working but I have already a database created and I want to read data from this database.

I am pushing the database to the sdcard and trying to run the application but it is not reading form the database. I want to know that if install this .apk file in device then my database will also shift to the device or not.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice is to store initial data on assets/raw folders of application resources. Then during 1st run just create DB using SQL scripts like:

```
create table if not exist
```

Fill DB with initial data - and here you're.